# Speeding up timestamp operations

Tags: python, pandas

The following transformation (ms -> datetime -> conver timezone) takes a long time to run (4 minutes), probably because I am working with a large dataframe:

```
for column in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
    # Data comes in unix time (ms) so I need to convert it to datetime
    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column], unit='ms')

    # Get times in EST
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
```

Is there any way to speed it up? Am I already using Pandas data structures and methods in the most efficient manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are available as DatetimeIndex methods which will be *much* faster:

```
df[column] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[column]).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Note: In 0.15.0 you'll have access to these as Series [dt accessor](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor):

```
df[column] = df[column].dt.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: Thanks, although the first option seems to not work for me on **0.14.1**. I get an error in `tz_localize` saying `TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`.

Comment: Andy, I don't have a `tz_localize` under my `.dt` namespace. Is that implemented? It'd be super useful.

Comment: @user815423426 that's strange, that sounds like the column has not correctly been converted to dates and hence DatetimeIndex fails... did your to_datetime line work - did you check the resulting dtype? It can be a bit finnickity.

Comment: @TomAugspurger I hadn't checked, I definitely thing we should add it!

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks. Yes. the first statement `pd.DateTimeIndex(df[column])` definitely 100% works.

Comment: @user815423426 that's bizarre, if I have a DatetimeIndex I just tested that I can `tz_localize`. Your error is odd/unhelpful! ...Do you already have tz info? I'm thinking perhaps there's something buggy here.

Comment: Thanks Andy -- I will try to put together an MWE with a few dates on the OP probably tomorrow. Thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by having `tz info`? Also, I don't think it matters but I am on Python 3 (latest stable as well). I also have the latest numpy, etc.

Comment: @user815423426 tzinfo is attribute to DatetimeIndex, has to be None to tz_localize. I wonder if this would be better as github issue, if there is a bug here, or new question, as I think it changes things from the original -nice - question!

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try in Bash using the date command. Date proves to be faster than even gawk for routine conversions. Python may struggle with this.

To speed this up even faster export the column in A in one temp file, column B in another, ect. (You can even do this in python). Then run the 5 columns in parallel.

```
for column in ['A']:
  print>>thefileA, column
for column in ['B']:
  print>>thefileB, column
```

Then a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray a < thefileA
for i in $( a ); do
    date -r item: $i
done
```

You'll want a master bash script to run the first part in python `python pythonscript.py`. Then you will want to call in each of the bash scripts in the background from the master `./FILEA.sh &`. That will run each column individually and will automatically designate nodes. For my bash loop after readarray, I'm not 100% that is the correct syntax. If you are on a linux, use `date -d @ item`.